# How to change a specify color in a major mode with Emacs

Tags: emacs, colors

I'm using `web-mode` with white background in Emacs.
Then the yellow color is too bright to see.

I want to make the yellow a little more darker.
Is there general way to change a specify color in a major mode, and how?

Or it's depends on each major mode how to change a specify color?

Comment: An important question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *are* general mechanisms for defining character colours and properties, but many ways in which they could be applied.

I would start by moving the cursor to one of the characters in question, and typing <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (or <kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-char`), which will give you lots of information, and will likely include a 'face' link which you can follow to get more information, including another link to the customize interface, where you should be able to edit it.

It's not always that simple, but there's a decent chance that this will be sufficient. Typically the name of the face will be a fair indication of whether you are editing the right thing.

Comment: Thanks! I've done with `(defun web-mode-hook ()
  (set-face-attribute 'web-mode-symbol-face nil :foreground "#FF7400"))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'web-mode-hook)`.

Comment: You do not need to do this on a mode hook. If that face is used only for that mode (which it sounds like), just customize the face: `M-x customize-face RET web-mode-symbol-face`.